# Entity Framework and Repository Pattern (problem with IQueryable)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, iqueryable

I just switched from Linq 2 SQL to Entity Framework, and I'm seeing some strange behaviors in EF that I'm hoping someone can help with.  I tried Googling around, but I wasn't able to find other people with this same problem.  I've mocked up a scenario to explain the situation.

If I work directly with an EF context, I'm able to do a select within a select.  For example, this executes perfectly fine:

```
        // this is an Entity Framework context that inherits from ObjectContext
        var dc = new MyContext();

        var companies1 = (from c in dc.Companies
                          select new {
                              Company = c,
                              UserCount = (from u in dc.CompanyUsers
                                           where u.CompanyId == c.Id
                                           select u).Count()
                          }).ToList();
```

However, if I use a repository pattern where the repository is returning IQueryable (or even ObjectSet or ObjectQuery), I get a NotSupportedException (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1)...

Here is an example of my repository:

```
public class Repository {
    private MyContext _dc;

    public Repository() {
        _dc = new MyContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies() {
        return _dc.Companies;
    }

    public IQueryable<CompanyUser> GetCompanyUsers() {
        return _dc.CompanyUsers;
    }
}
```

// I'm using the repository inside another class (e.g. in my Services layer)

```
        var repository = new Repository();

        var companies2 = (from c in repository.GetCompanies()
                          select new {
                              Company = c,
                              UserCount = (from u in repository.GetCompanyUsers()
                                           where u.CompanyId == c.Id
                                           select u).Count()
                          }).ToList();
```

The above code throws a NotSupportedException.

I realize that if there's an association between Companies and CompanyUsers, then I can simply do this and it will work fine:

```
        var companies3 = (from c in repository.GetCompanies()
                          select new {
                              Company = c,
                              UserCount = (from u in c.CompanyUsers
                                           select u).Count()
                          }).ToList();
```

...but my example is just a simplified version of a more complicated scenario where I don't have an association between the entities.

So I'm very confused why Entity Framework is throwing the NotSupportedException.  How is it that the query works perfectly fine when I'm working with the EF context directly, but it's not supported if I'm working with IQueryable returned from another method.  This worked perfectly fine with Linq 2 SQL, but it doesn't seem to work in Entity Framework.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that what's happening is that EF sees the expression for `repository.GetCompanyUsers()` inside the lambda for the first `select` and doesn't know what to do with it because `repository` isn't an EF context. I think that if you pass in the IQueryable directly instead of an expression that returns it, it should work.

How about if you do this:

```
    var companyUsers = repository.GetCompanyUsers();
    var companies2 = (from c in repository.GetCompanies() 
                      select new { 
                          Company = c, 
                          UserCount = (from u in companyUsers 
                                       where u.CompanyId == c.Id 
                                       select u).Count() 
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why we need do that way, I mean we have association here?

Comment: This requires two round trips to the server though... wait, does it?

Comment: Gabe, you're absolutely right. I'm still confused why EF can't handle the expression, but your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Rei, there will only be one round trip to the database, as the first expression will not trigger the database query until it's executed inside the the second expression.  I confirmed this with SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those strange quirks with Linq to SQL/EF. Apparently they implemented a way to translate from a getter *property* to SQL, but not a way to translate from a getter *function* to SQL.

If instead of a function `GetCompanyUsers()` you use a property like `CompanyUsers`, it should work.

Weird eh?

So instead of

```
public IQueryable<CompanyUser> GetCompanyUsers() {
    return _dc.CompanyUsers;
}
```

You might do

```
public IQueryable<CompanyUser> CompanyUsers {
    get { return _dc.CompanyUsers; }
}
```

As far as parameterized queries go (which you can't do with a property, obviously), see my question answered here: [Custom function in Entity Framework query sometimes translates properly, sometimes doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392481/custom-function-in-entity-framework-query-sometimes-translates-properly-sometime)

You can also have `wheres` and `selects` in the property too; they'll translate fine. For instance, if I had a blog with an Articles table that contains some articles that aren't online:

```
public IQueryable<Article> LiveArticles {
    get { return _dc.Articles.Where(a => !a.IsDraft); }
}
```

That'll also reduce the number of parameterized queries that you need.

Comment: Very weird, but you're absolutely right.  Properties that return IQueryable work with EF.  Linq to SQL also worked with methods, but I guess EF didn't implement that.