# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method with Let Statement

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am in the process of converting an application that uses LINQ to SQL over to LINQ to Entities. I use a repository pattern and I have run in a problem that works in LINQ to SQL but not Entities.

In my data layer, I use LINQ statements to fill my object graph so that none of my database entities are exposed anywhere else. In this example, I have a Lookup Respository that returns a list of Categories. It looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<Entities.DomainModels.Category> getCategories()
    {
        return (from c in Categories
                where !c.inactive
                orderby c.categoryName
                select new Entities.DomainModels.Category
                {
                    id = c.categoryID,
                    category = c.categoryName,
                    inactive = c.inactive
                });
    }
```

Later, I want to put the categories into a sub query and it looks like this:

```
var d = from p in Programs
    let categories = (from pc in p.Categories
                      join c in getCategories() on pc.categoryID equals c.id
                      select c)
   select new 
    {
        id = p.id,
        title = p.title
       categories = categories.ToList()
        };
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Entities.DomainModels.Category] getCategories()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

For reference, the following works though it doesn't return the data I need (it's basically a join):

```
var q = from p in Programs
    from pc in p.Categories
    join c in getCategories() on pc.categoryID equals c.id
    select new 
    {
        id = p.id,
            category = c
        };
```

I understand what the error means in concept however LINQ to SQL would make it work. I have this pattern throughout my data layer and I really want to keep it. Should this be working? If not, how can I modify it without mixing my layers.

Comment: You are trying to use a .net function which cannot be translated into an SQL statement, thats the reason you get that error. If join works  for you, then you need to trace the SQL generated by the join and check whats going wrong with the query. What is the relation between Programs and Categories?

Comment: Programs can have many categories. This query works exactly as-is in LINQ to SQL. I think my exact issue is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290491/entity-framework-and-repository-pattern-problem-with-iqueryable  I wonder if this has improved in 3 years.

Comment: It seems like a fix for this may have been included in EF 6.0. See http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/808

Comment: This scenario is partially fixed in EF 6.0. I still can't call my getCategories() directly however if I copy the code of that function into my LET statement, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You cant pass     `getCategories()`   to EF.

The query must be destructible to expression tree.

Calculate getCategories() first.

eg

```
var simpleList = getCategories().Select(id).Tolist;
```

then use a contains

```
where(t=> simpleList.Contains(t.CatId)   // or the query syntax equivalent
```

Comment: What about performance? Query plan for queries with IEnumerable.Contains can't be cached